# beanstalkd weirdness, returns invalid jobs

Tags: php, beanstalkd

beanstalkd is playing tricks on me. As you can see from the following series of commands, there are ready jobs, but I cant peek, delete, or do anything with them.

```
watch ab_similar_sync_node
WATCHING 1

stats-tube ab_similar_sync_node
OK 272
---
name: ab_similar_sync_node
current-jobs-urgent: 0
current-jobs-ready: 8521
current-jobs-reserved: 0
current-jobs-delayed: 0
current-jobs-buried: 0
total-jobs: 205999
current-using: 0
current-watching: 1
current-waiting: 0
cmd-pause-tube: 0
pause: 0
pause-time-left: 0

peek-ready
NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 5):

`peek` and `peek_ready` work with the tube being use, not watched. `reserve` will look in the tubes being watched, but as you can watch multiple tubes, it's not appropriate for peek.

`use ab_similar_sync_node` first and then you'll be able to peek all you want.